# Override chrome absolute positioning left:0

Tags: css, absolute

I have a div with the following css:

```
#div
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

I want this div to be positioned on the top right of its container. However, I found in the Chrome inspector that there is a style as follows:

```
element.style { left:0; }
```

When I uncheck this style in Chrome the div floats to the correct position. The issue is that because I am displaying from the right, the left should be set to none. Is there a way I can override this CSS to not render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `left:auto !important;`.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is `left: 100%;` and see if that works.